# .exe file is not working in some systems. created using Launch4J s/w

Tags: java, swt, launch4j

I am working in windows swt desktop app. I need to create an installer for that I have used Launch4J s/w.

**Requirements:** - Windows 32 or 64 bit and Java 32 bit.

Here problem is .exe working fine in some systems and it is not working in some systems.

App stops after opening splash screen.

Also in some systems, App working fine. but getting a dialog box from Launch4J s/w saying that "An error occurred while starting the application."

Comment: No. How can we see the error message when app is not opening in some other machine in which it is not developed. Also I tried to find error from Control panel - Administrative Tools - Event Viewer, there is nothing.

Comment: You can always use [Java VisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) for inspecting what's going on, provided you are using recent versions of java.

Comment: @NaderhadjiGhanbari : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: probleem met de com
 at jmtp.PortableDeviceManagerImplWin32.<init>(PortableDeviceManagerImplWin32.java:52)
 at jmtp.PortableDeviceManager.<init>(PortableDeviceManager.java:34)
 at FindFile.main(FindFile.java:96)
this is the exception I am getting. But this error is there in another xp system.

Comment: Can you post the entire Stack Trace? BTW what do you mean by 'Another XP System'?